# wordpress user roles based on departments

Tags: php, wordpress, roles

This is my scenario in wordpress. This is a company website. Company has many departments like news, marketing, after sales and so on. For each department, there is an author (only one author, who is the head of the particular department). Each author in various department has multiple editors. Each editor can post content to the site, but he cannot publish. The author of the particular department will read the content and publish it later. Can you help me to find some plugins for this hierarchy.

Also, author of the particular department can view /edit / publish only the posts by his editors. He should not view or edit other department editors post.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you are looking for, you are able to create/edit/delete user roles with this plugin.
[WPFront User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfront-user-role-editor/)